# Array Not renumbering

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have a situation where I have to delete a obj from an array vs .splice. What is happening is that the array is not renumbering correctly, as you can see below.

To get rid of the undefined placeholder in the array after i delete an object for the array i do a [].concat(). The problem with this is that the new array is not numbered correctly.

What is the most effective what to renumber the new array correctly with low overhead?

```
for (var o = 0; o < uncheckedQue[i].childNodes.length; o += 1) {
    uncheckedQue[i].removeChild(uncheckedQue[i].childNodes[o]);
    if (uncheckedQue[i].childNodes.length < 1) {
        delete uncheckedQue[i];//remove the document fragment if has no childnodes
    };
};

 uncheckedQue = [].concat(uncheckedQue);


0: DocumentFragment
2: DocumentFragment
3: DocumentFragment
4: DocumentFragment
5: DocumentFragment
6: DocumentFragment
7: DocumentFragment
length: 8
```

***Let me clear something up. These childNodes are contained in a document fragment that is in an array. These childNodes are not in the Dom.

Here is the outer loop. You'll notice why i use the delete, so i keep my length correct for the outer loop.

```
     for (var i = 0; i < uncheckedQue.length; i += 1) {
                 //
                 if (t.mucs === t.mucsstop) { break; };
                 for (var o = 0; o < uncheckedQue[i].childNodes.length; o += 1) {
                     uncheckedQue[i].removeChild(uncheckedQue[i].childNodes[o]);
                     t.mucs += 1;
                     if (uncheckedQue[i].childNodes.length < 1) {
                         delete uncheckedQue[i];//remove the document fragment if has no childnodes
                     };
                     if (t.mucs === t.mucsstop) { break; };
                 };
             };
```

Comment: Is this the inner loop of a nested loop or something?

Answer (score 2):

[`childNodes`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1451460987) is a **live** NodeList, so each time you remove an item, the list is shorter so you effectively skip every second node. If you want to remove all childNodes from a document fragment, the simplest way is to keep removing firstChild nodes until there are no more:

```
var node = uncheckedQue[i];
while (node.firstChild) {
  node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}
```

Also, a NodeList is a host object, it is not an array, so calling array methods on it will throw errors.

### Edit

From your code:

```
> for (var o = 0; o < uncheckedQue[i].childNodes.length; o += 1) {
```

That would be clearer in a common format:

```
for (var j=0; j < uncheckedQue[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
```

If `uncheckedQue` is an array of document fragments, then:

```
> uncheckedQue[i].removeChild(uncheckedQue[i].childNodes[o]);
```

is removing child nodes from a fragment. So the child node that is now at `childNodes[o]` is the one that was at `childNodes[o + 1]` before that statement was executed. So on the next iteration, the `o + 1` node will be the one that was formerly at `o + 2`. In simple terms, it will remove every second child.

Also:

```
> if (uncheckedQue[i].childNodes.length < 1) {
```

can be:

```
if (!uncheckedQue[i].childNodes.length) {
```

since the [length value](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-203510337) of a NodeList is an unsigned integer from 0, and if length is zero then the test returns true.

To remove the fragment from the array, use [Array.prototype.splice](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12) as suggested by VeXii. But note that you must adjust the index or work backwards through the array for the same reason as when deleting a member of a live NodeList.

> You'll notice why i use the delete, so i keep my length correct for the outer loop.

Because the delete operator doesn't adjust the array member indexes (which are just property names), so you have a sparse array. You can either use splice and adjust the index as you go, or go backwards through the array, or compress the array at the end (which is likely the worst performing solution), e.g.

```
function compressArray(a) {
  for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    while (!a.hasOwnProperty(i) && a.length > i) {
      a.splice(i, 1);
    } 
  }
  return a;
}
```

Note that the above modifies the original array. It's simpler to copy array members to a new array:

```
function compressArray(a) {
  for (var i=0, iLen=a.length, b=[]; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      b.push(a[i]);
    } 
  }
  return b;
}
```

Take your pick. Note that neither method removes members whose value is `undefined` or some other falsey value, only those that don't exist at all.

Comment: I am not deleting the childnodes I am deleting the DocumentFragment. A document fragment is the container for the childnodes. See the array.

Comment: You are deleting child nodes, unless you have a function `removeChild` and property `childNodes` that operate on document fragments differently to the same named DOM equivalents. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

insted of delete use splice like

```
if (uncheckedQue[i].childNodes.length < 1) {
   uncheckedQue.splice(i,1)//remove the document fragment if has no childnodes
};
```

Comment: Note that if doing this, unless going backwards through the array, the counter `i` must be adjusted since the member that was formerly `i + 1` is now at `i`.